# Unity Physics2D.OverlapBox always returns false

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I'm trying to use Physics2D.OverlapBox to check if a collider is underneath the mouse when it's being clicked.
OverlapArea and OverlapCircle works, but OverlapBox doesn't, and I'm not sure why!

Here's the code

```
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePosition.z = 10;
        Vector2 position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);
        bool colliderHere = Physics2D.OverlapBox(mousePosition, new Vector2(3,3), 0, roomLayer);
        Debug.Log(position + " — " + colliderHere);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use a box with a width and length of 3 units each, centered around the mouse position.
This always returns false for some reason. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you saying if you swap overlapbox out with area or circle it returns true?

Comment: This is just a shot in the dark but, what happens if you don't set the Z position to 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `mousePosition` instead of `position` to the `OverlapBox` method, that's why it doesn't work.

Moreover, remember that `OverlapBox` will return `null` (and thus `colliderHere = false`) if you click on a collider which is a trigger IF the setting `Queries Hit Triggers` in the `Physics 2D` is off.